# xsltproc: how to set attribute from attribute-set via command line?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have in my xsl file something like this:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="section.level1.properties">
  <xsl:attribute name="break-before">page</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

all works fine. But now I want to change this behaviour online.

Before that I used --stringparam for single attribute changes.
So I try

```
--stringparam /section.level1.properties/break-before page
--param /section.level1.properties/break-before "'page'"
```

Also I try

```
--xinclude ./docbook_sect_page_break.xsl
```

where in ./docbook_sect_page_break.xsl I put my code.

The last attempt cause empty output, the first two cause no effect (no page break).

**Update**
Also I try

```
--param xsl:attribute-set[@name='section.level1.properties']/xsl:attribute[@name='break-before'] "'page'"
```

Without success.

So question, how can I set attribute from attribute-set via command line of xsltproc?

Comment: You can only set parameters from the command line to override default values.  Parameters are tagged as <xsl:param name="somename" >default value</xsl:param>    An attribute set is not a parameter. What behavior do you want to change?

Comment: This parameter(attribute) control insert or not insert page break at the end of sect1. Actually from user point of view attributes and parameters in docbook are very similar. They control output file. Looks like docbook developers use parameter for logically single parameters and attribute-set to union logically similar parameters.